# Download a file from sharepoint returns bigger file size

Tags: c#, sharepoint, download

I try to download a file from sharepoint using below method in my ASP.NET Project (C#).
It always return a bigger file size and sometimes it returns corrupted file.
What's wrong with it . I try so many ContentType but still the same.
It must prompt user the download dialog.

```
           //file is SPFile
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            //response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= \"" + FileName + "\"");
            response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            if (file.Length != 0)
            {
                response.BinaryWrite(file.OpenBinary());
            }
            response.Flush();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most probably your not closing your response stream, and it appends the rest of your .aspx file or master file html content.

Comment: I use ContentType: application/x-download, but I copy file content to another file (document set files, actually, compressing to single zip) and use fileInfo.Length

Comment: @MarekKembrowski- > how to close the response stream for my case ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SalientBrain -> x-download ? I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @MarekKembrowski - > Thanks for your answer again !!! After adding repsonse.End(), it's working well.

Comment: I still got the issues in IE 8. Can it be related with any of those ContentType and Header ?